# How to convert audio and change its quality bitrate?

Tags: command-line, sound, mp3, conversion, wav

I want to **convert** `mp3`/`wav` audio file into `wav` format with a specific bitrate quality of `16`bit or any if possible. How can I **convert** this file as well as change its **quality** bitrate in *ubuntu linux 18.04*?

Comment: What OS/release ?   (*not all options are available for all releases*)

Comment: It's _Ubuntu Linux 18.04_. I've edited my question

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean by 'bitrate quality of 16bit' but I suspect that FFmpeg could help you out with something like: `ffmpeg -i my_input_file.mp3 -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 44100 my_output_file.wav`. Different options for the output wav file can be seen with `ffmpeg -formats | grep PCM`.

Answer (score 2):

SoX is "the Swiss Army knife of audio manipulation". With that tool, you can read and write audio files in different formats, and you even can apply effects to them. Install sox with:

```
sudo apt install sox
```

Read about how it works:

```
man sox
```